# Как заменить блок текста в Perl?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

К примеру есть такой кусок:

```
<param VARIABLE>
    TEXT_TO_REPLACE
</param>
```

как мне сделать замену TEXT_TO_REPLACE  с поиском по VARIABLE?

Comment: как-то так `$string =~ s/(\<param $find\>).*?(\<\/param\>)/\1$newtext\2/gi;`

Comment: К сожалению, это работает если нет переноса строки \n. Как мне добавить учет новой строки?

Comment: `$string =~ s/(\<param $find\>).*?(\<\/param\>)/\1$newtext\2/gis;`

Comment: Спасибо! Работает отлично!

Answer (score 3):

*Ответ из комментариев* от [@Andrzej A. Filip](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191419/andrzej-a-filip)

```
$string =~ s/(\<param $find\>).*?(\<\/param\>)/\1$newtext\2/gis;
```